# Best options for an AngularJS Tree Grid

Tags: angularjs, gridview, treeview, lazy-loading

For a while now, I've been looking for a Tree Grid that works nicely with AngularJS and haven't had a lot of luck.

My requirements are:

1. Easy to use
2. Looks good
3. Supports drag and drop
4. Can handle large amount of data 10000+ (i.e pagination/lazy scroll of 10,000+ rows)
5. Can show hierarchical data in a table (i.e columns/sorting)
6. Free/Cheap

Projects that come close:

- [Sencha Tree Grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid)

  - Doesn't appear to play nicely with AngularJS
  - Apparently a Buffered-Tree module can help handle 1000s or rows
- [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/JimLiu/angular-ui-tree)

  - Close but doesn't support table functions like columns, out of the box
  - Doesn't handle large data, but Michael Bromley's dirPaginate directive can fix this
- [tree-grid-directive](https://github.com/khan4019/tree-grid-directive)

  - Looks good (Fits with bootstrap)
  - Has columns
  - But doesn't easily allow for pagination/lazy loading

Ok... so given that other people must have solved this before, my question is:

**What is the best way to approach this?**

Is there a project out there already that covers all the bases?
Or perhaps there is a simple way to adapt one of these to be a lazily-loaded tree grid...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Suggestion would be Angular UI-Grid. In its current version, there are many configuration options, also for Trees:

Website: http://ui-grid.info/

Expandable Grid: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid

Comment: It says the feature is in alpha.  Have you seen any issues because of this?

Answer (score 5):

[IgniteUI Tree Grid](http://www.igniteui.com/tree-grid/overview) (not to be confused with the ugly [Hierarchical Grid](http://www.igniteui.com/hierarchical-grid/overview))

Whilst not perfect, this seems like a reasonable option.

**Pros**

- Looks nice enough
- Has a few plugins for sorting, filtering, paging, pinning etc.
- Lazy loading of children can be integrated by listening to expand events (and possibly the [InfragisticsLoader](http://www.igniteui.com/loader/overview))

**Cons**

- No out-of-the-box AngularJS integration
- No "Infinite Scroll" out-of-the-box

Its also pretty simple to use:

```
$("#treegrid").igTreeGrid({
    width: "100%",
    dataSource: data,
    primaryKey: "employeeID",
    columns: [
        { headerText: "Employee ID", key: "employeeID", dataType: "number" },
        { headerText: "Name", key: "name", dataType: "string" }
    ]
});
```

I have created a sample jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/immersion/qggbs0s6/

Comment: There actually exists an angular-igniteui directive for TreeGrid (http://igniteui.github.io/igniteui-angular/samples/igTreeGrid.html) which seems to do a nice job too. I haven't had a chance to try to get paging/infinite-scroll going yet though...

Comment: After fighting with Infragistrics IgniteUI for a fair few hours, I'm ready to admit defeat.  Your jsFiddle is great, but falls into the same trick that their own demos use... the JSON data is hardcoded.  Now, try using a real Angular controller, where you load the data in from a web service.  I haven't tried the tree control, but Infragistrics admits that the hierarchical grids "don't support 1 or 2 way binding" !!  It's shockingly unfinished and poorly documented.

Answer (score 5):

I know its a two months old question, but I needed the same thing and just came across this grid [Adapt-Strap](http://adaptv.github.io/adapt-strap/##tablelite).

I used it some small examples and worked fine so far, seems really easy to use, has drag-drop/pagination/lazy loading.

I think its worth a try, and fyi: I have no connection what so ever with the developers there.

Comment: Yeah looks good... but it doesn't look like that the **Tree Browser** component has all the other nice features I.e drag-drop/pagination/lazy loading. I could be wrong though...

Comment: Hey, 

It has lazy loading, see Table AJAX.
It has pagination and drag drop - see Table Lite (from the  top menu)

The only thing I do not like about adapt-strap grid is that it uses tables to render data, and I really hate tables.

Comment: @bolovan I am confused. Are you saying those components can be incorporated into the **Tree Browser**? If not, the point stands that **Tree Browser** does not have drag drop/pagination/lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

[Angular Tree Grid](https://github.com/debabratapatra/angular-tree-grid) seems like a nice option if you want to be able to edit nodes.

As of version 2.7, it does *not* support drag & drop reordering, sadly.

Demo: https://angular-tree-grid.stackblitz.io/add_edit_delete

Comment: do you know by chance which version of angular tree grid is compatible with AngularJS? The current site looks like its using Angular and doesnt make it clear which version is for AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Use JS Tree

http://ezraroi.github.io/ngJsTree/?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation

Lazy Load in JSTree :http://www.miketyka.com/2012/10/lazy-loading-with-jstree-and-ajax/

Comment: Thanks, looks nice but it still doesn't provide the grid/table functionality so it is very much like the 'angular-ui-tree' I noted in the question.

Comment: You can add extra columns using https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid, but it's buggy and unmaintained, unfortunately.