# Angular JS hierarchical grid

Tags: angularjs, gridview, treeview

I am looking for hierarchical grid using angular JS. I came across Adapt-Strap grid, but it doesn't support sorting,filtering and pagination of columns. Is there any other hierarchical grid that supports filtering,sorting and pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a very similar question here: [Best options for an AngularJS Tree Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241548/best-options-for-an-angularjs-tree-grid?rq=1)

The best answer (currently at least) is probably Angular UI-Grid

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/319_complex_trees

It's not actually that amazing, but is the best I've found so far...